# Index of element in list

Tags: python, list, indexing, max, min

I want to find out if the maximum value in a list has a smaller index than the minimum value in a list. If there are two or more indices with the minimum value, I want to look at the greatest index. If there are two or more indices with the maximum value, I want to look at the smallest index. Now my code looks like this:

```
maximum = max(lijst)
minimum = minimum(lijst)

if lijst.index(maximum) <= lijst.index(minimum):
...
```

But this doesn't give me the indices I want with these kind of lists:

```
[2, 9, 15, 36, 36, 3, 2, 36]
```

Now I want to look at the largest index of the minimum value (which is 6 in this case) and the smallest index for the maximum value (which is 3 in this case). Does someone know how to find these indices?

Comment: Just to be clear, so you are trying to check if the first maximum value is before the last minimum value?

Comment: @MoonCheesez I want to check if there is an occurence of the maximum value before an occurence of the minimum value, so if there exists an $x$ with $x=max$ and an $y$ with $y=min$ and $index.x >= index.y$.

Comment: What is the expected behavior multiple minimum and maximum indices? With your example, what is the expected value and the actual value generated from the program?

Answer (score 0):

you can return the min/max value in a list using `min`/`max`, then use `enumerate` to get indices, then apply another `min`/`max` of the indicies list, example:

```
my_list = [2, 9, 15, 36, 36, 3, 2, 36]    
maxval = max(my_list)

indices = [index for index, val in enumerate(my_list) if val == maxval]
[3, 4, 7]
maxIndex = max(indices)
7
```

So if you want to check if maximum before the minimum, then return each value's index and compare the two.

Comment: I like your use of list comprehension.

Comment: i find it really useful in lots of situations.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Python's find function. You can find the last minimum value by continuing to check until find returns -1.

```
maximum = max(li)
minimum = minimum(li)

i1 = li.find(maximum)
i2 = li.find(minimum)
found = False
while(not found):
    if li.find(minimum, i2+1) != -1:
        i2 = li.find(minimum, i2+1)
    else:
        found = True

if i1 < i2:
.......
```

Answer (score 0):

## What you probably had in mind

Although there are other answers I wanted to work on something along the lines of your code. It may not be the most efficient but I believe it is what you had in mind:

```py
my_list = [2, 9, 15, 36, 36, 3, 2, 36]
maximum = max(my_list)
minimum = min(my_list)

first_maximum_index = my_list.index(maximum)
last_minimum_index = len(my_list)-1 - my_list[::-1].index(minimum)

if first_maximum_index <= last_minimum_index:
    print("Yes!")
```

`.index()` gets the index of the first value in the list. So, to get the last minimum value, you need to reverse the list before using `.index()` which is this portion:

```py
my_list[::-1].index(minimum)
```

After that you will get the index of the minimum value BUT it is the index of the reversed list. Now, you have to "reverse" this index by substracting the number of indices, `len(my_list)-1` which gives you the final expression:

```py
len(my_list)-1 - my_list[::-1].index(minimum)
```

After that, you can compare the indices as you did.

## A more efficient method

Now, here's a more efficient solution (though longer, and perhaps less readable). If you notice, you are running through the list about 4 times (worst case) in the code above. You can reduce it to running through the list once:

```py
my_list = [2, 9, 15, 36, 36, 3, 36]

# Step 1
current_min = float("inf")
current_max = float("-inf")
is_before = False

for val in my_list:
    if val > current_max:
        is_before = False
        current_max = val

    if val <= current_min:
        current_min = val
        is_before = True


if is_before:
    print("Yes!")
```

The trick here is to think about subsets of the list:

```
[2] # ???
[2, 9] # False
[2, 9, 15] # False
[2, 9, 15, 36] # False
[2, 9, 15, 36, 36] # False
[2, 9, 15, 36, 36, 3] # False
[2, 9, 15, 36, 36, 3, 2] # True
[2, 9, 15, 36, 36, 3, 2, 36] # True
```

If you look closely, the result changes from `True` to `False` when there is a new maximum value. Similarly, the result changes from `False` to `True` when there is a new or existing minimum value introduced at the end of the list.

These correspond to the block of code:

```py
    # If value introduced is the new maximum
    if val > current_max:
        is_before = False
        current_max = val

    # If value introduced is an existing or new minimum
    if val <= current_min:
        current_min = val
        is_before = True
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the index of the first maximum:

```
l.index(max(l))
```

To get the index of the last minimum you can reverse the list and apply something similar:

```
l.reverse()
len(l)-l.index(min(l))-1
```